# Adding an Object to another Objetct VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I created two classes, the first one is a Fluid, and the second one is a Heat Exchanger.

The Heat Exchanger has to contain 2 fluids, but I don't know how to add the fluid into the exchanger...

```
Sub test()
Dim water As cFluide
Set water = New cFluide
water.Temp_init = 49.1
water.Temp_out = 36.6
water.Flow_init = 124.4

Dim HX As cHX
Set HX = New cHX

Dim Fluide_1 As cFluide
Set Fluide_1 = New cFluide

HX.Fluide_1 = water
End Sub
```

I keep getting the following error

> '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Would anyone have any idea on this?

Here is the definition of the cHX class:

```
Dim HXSurface As Single
Dim HXh As Single
Dim HXType As String

Dim HXFluide_1 As cFluide
Dim HXFluide_2 As cFluide

Public Property Get Surface() As Single
    Surface = HXSurface
End Property

Public Property Let Surface(S As Single)
    HXSurface = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(0, S)
End Property

Public Property Get h() As Single
    h = HXh
End Property

Public Property Let h(h As Single)
    HXh = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(0, h)
End Property

Public Property Get Type_HX() As String
    Type_HX = HXType
End Property

Public Property Let Type_HX(t As String)
    HXType = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(0, t)
End Property

Public Property Get Fluide_1() As cFluide
    Fluide_1 = HXFluide_1
End Property

Public Property Let Fluide_1(f_1 As cFluide)
    HXFluide_1 = f_1
End Property

Public Property Get Fluide_2() As cFluide
    Fluide_2 = HXFluide_2
End Property

Public Property Let Fluide_2(f_2 As cFluide)
    HXFluide_2 = f_2
End Property
```

Comment: Try `Set HX.Fluide_1 = water`.

Comment: It dosn't work either... But thanks anyway

Comment: You've established no relationship between HX and Fluide_1 so I don't see how Fluide_1 is a member of HX.

Comment: What do you mean? I declared Fluide_1 in the HX class the same way I did for Temp_init in the Fluide Class for example

Comment: Your `Dim Fluide_1` and  `HX.Fluide_1` are completely different things if thats the confusion?  You should add the property set code for `Fluide_1` in `cHX`

Comment: I would like to see the `cHX` class, particularly where the `Fluide_1` property is set as well. That is almost definitely the culprit.

Comment: Here you go, added it to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign an object reference you must always use `Set`.

The property syntax is `Set` instead of `Let`:

```
Public Property Set Fluide_1(f_1 As cFluide)
    Set HXFluide_1 = f_1
End Property
```

And in the client:

```
Set HX.Fluide_1 = water
```

Answer (score 0):

We are dealing with objects here so they need to be "Set". Here is a very simplistic example of how you could approach this in setting up you `cHX` class:

```
Option Explicit

Private oFluid1 As Object 'cFluid
Private oFluid2 As Object 'cFluid

Public Property Get Fluid1() As Object 'cFluid
    Set Fluid1 = oFluid1
End Property

Public Property Let Fluid1(oFld As Object) 'cFluid)
    Set oFluid1 = oFld 
End Property

Public Property Get Fluid2() As Object 'cFluid
    Set Fluid2 = oFluid2
End Property

Public Property Let Fluid2(oFld As Object) 'cFluid)
    Set oFluid2 = oFld 
End Property
```

Please note that the fluids can be set, alternatively, as a single array variable. Also, you can declare them `AS cFluid` if so desired.

Somewhere in your project, you would refer to these class objects as follows:

```
Sub a()
    Dim HX As cHX
    Dim water1 As cFluid
    Dim water2 As cFluid

    Set HX = New cHX
    Set water1 = New cFluid
    Set water2 = New cFluid
    '.....
    Set HX.Fluid1 = water1
    Set HX.Fluid2 = water2
End Sub
```

I hope this resolves the present difficulty.

Comment: @Tim You are certainly welcome, Tim. My first impulse was to tell you to "just pour" but then I thought better of it, as you can see :) Good luck with VBA!